# Embedding Azure Application Insights into third party applications

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, azure-application-insights

Is there anyway that we can embed an Azure Applications Insight dashboard into one of our third party sites to allow our client the ability to view the information that it provides?

I initially thought about using an iFrame to do this however most sites now use `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` which prevent iFrames from viewing the site.

I also know that it could be possible to build these dashboards manually using the API however it would be much better to simply get the embedded code for the metrics graphs created in the Azure Portal.

Has anybody been able to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use PowerBI to run these for you. Once the report is within PowerBI you can make it accessible by either providing their email or by making the report public.

However, it wont be the dashboard, you will have to import the individual reports/graphs to create a dashboard within PowerBI.

If you view your reports within Logs(Analytics), there's an export button that contains a link to generate the script that PowerBI uses to build the same report.

[image]